# Why do professors give talks on published work without their coauthors present at the seminars?

Tags: seminars, research-dissemination

They simply say that it is joint work with somebody.

Is it primarily because one is a better speaker than the other?  Like, do some professors publish a lot but choose to stay behind the scenes and let their coauthors present the work?

Comment: So you want the whole research team to show up at every talk? Who has the time for that?

Comment: @JonCuster And not only the time, but,  frequently, the funding to bring  the whole team to a conference.

Comment: Does this question evoke imagery of 8-12 identically-dressed researchers standing in front of an audience, speaking in perfect unison for anyone else? Or just me?

Comment: This would also be highly impractical for a collaboration of a thousand people, all of whom are listed as authors on the paper. In fact several of these people might be giving talks in different rooms at the same time.

Comment: In my field, it's traditional for the _least_ experienced coauthor (usually a student) to give the talk at the conference where the paper is published. Otherwise, how would they get any exposure, or even learn to give good talks?

Comment: What would be the benefit of having all the authors present?

Comment: Because some of the co-authors (like me) have responsibilities or preferences that make it difficult to travel to conferences?  Or because we're back at the lab doing productive work instead of spending several days hanging around hotels and airline terminals?  Or because research grants don't extend to paying for flights, hotels, and conference fees for several people?

Comment: Can I downvote this question? When the CEO or head engineer introduces a new product, do they invite the whole team, or the whole factory?

Comment: I share @Thomas's question. If something costs time and/or money, it won't happen unless there is a positive enough benefit. The question seems to assume that the default should be all authors present, unless there is some specific reason for an author to be absent. Why?

Comment: The only time I was in a situation like this, I was giving a talk on something else I had been working on and there was only enough money at my two co-author's university for one of them to attend the conference.

Comment: There are cases where none of the authors can manage/afford to join the seminar.

Answer (score 77):

An incomplete list:

- Because they're invited to give a talk, and their coauthor(s) aren't.
- Because their coauthor(s) can't afford to travel to every talk they give on that piece of research.
- Because their coauthor(s) are busy with other things.
- Because this way they and their coauthor(s) can disseminate their ideas more widely, by giving more talks for the same overall investment of time.
- Because the work is interdisciplinary, and the conference at which the work is being presented is devoted to some of the disciplines involved but not all of them, so attending would be irrelevant for the coauthor(s).

(Thanks to the commenters who suggested further additions.)

Comment: Great list. Another one is that different authors may be expert at different aspects and the conference is only relevant for one of the authors)

Comment: Also: Because the work was interdisciplinary, and the conference has little to do with one author's field of work but a lot with another's.

Comment: Also: Because in certain disciplines (physics), it's entirely normal to have hundreds of coauthors.

Comment: @chrylis - True, but only in narrowly restricted subfields of physics (e.g.  experimental work in particle physics done at large accelerators). Even in the field of high-energy physics, most work seems to be theoretical (with a handful of authors), with only a few experimental papers (with hundreds of authors). For example, take a look at the [Journal of High Energy Physics](https://link.springer.com/journal/13130/2017/7/page/2).

Comment: The point being, no physicist would be surprised to see hundreds of authors in experimental papers coming out of CERN, but a mere seven authors on a computational modeling paper (seen recently in my department) would be quite surprising. And hundreds of authors on an experimental paper in anything *but* high-energy physics *would* be pretty unusual.

Comment: @Obie2.0 All of my personal experience is in HEP, and I've been on page 5 of a 7-page author list in 8-point type. ;-)

Comment: @chrylis - Ah, very nice. Well, you probably know that outside of HEP and related fields, even within physics, that would be pretty uncommon. Or even in HEP in theory papers, I believe.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Sure, but *reductio ad absurdum* works well as an answer here!

Comment: Even without the absurdity of HEP, it's perfectly possible to have never met your co-authors, who are based on another continent. But as a footnote to the list, all authors should have a grasp of the whole paper, *and know their limits*.  This might lead to: "That's a really interesting question, but Jane would be much better able to answer it than me.  I can only tell you that... but we can discuss it afterwards"

Comment: @chrylis Or thousands, depending on the experiment... ATLAS's current author list looks to be about 2700, while CMS' is about 2200.

Answer (score 49):

The [average immunology paper has 11 authors](http://phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1911); so does the average molecular biology paper.  Genetics papers average 21.6 authors. High energy and nuclear physics papers, 226.8.

In many cases talks will cover multiple papers, so there could easily be 50 co-authors involved.  In many cases, these include authors from many different institutions, countries, and continents.

And talks are not a particularly big deal in many fields. In my fields, a moderately well-known scientist might give 5-10 talks a year. A post-doc looking for a faculty position might give far more than that.

Who is going to pay my fifty co-authors to travel to five talks a year?  I have a hard enough time getting reimbursed for myself.

I don't even understand what the point would be.  Presumably they'd sit in the front row? And ... smile and wave? Or would they run up to the podium when there's a slide they know about and take over for thirty seconds, and then run back to their seat?

The more I think about it, the more baffled I am. I guess the short answer is, There's no point, no one cares.

Comment: *226.8* authors per paper?!  How do they even fit that on the title page?

Comment: @Prime Well, the record for a paper (particle physics) is of around 5000 authors.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano (1) Invite them all to your talk. (2) Take a photo of the room. (3) Show it to your mom.  (4) Profit!

Comment: @Prime It's a lot easier than when the 0.8th author has to give their research talk.

Comment: @Prime Sometimes they do give a multi-page author list and don't start the article until the second or third page, but in most of the extreme cases the author list is printed after the paper appendix. ([example](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.191803))

Comment: What do you mean you don't understand what the point would be, you nailed it perfectly - for them to smile and wave, clap really loudly, and use the clicker at inopportune times

Comment: I love that the first one in your list with a fractional number of authors is Genetics

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I remember reading about a paper from a distributed computing project that tried to claim the title by listing all of the 10s or 100s of 1000s of people who donated CPU time.  The journal only let them include a link to that list in a footnote though.

Comment: I'm starting a research internship soon (not physics), and was told that if I make a significant contribution, I can be listed as an author. You're telling me that in physics research, one paper can have several hundred people make significant contributions?

Comment: @Shokhet there are links to papers with several hundred authors. Are you claiming that such papers don't exist, or suggesting that for some reason the journals abandoned their authorship criteria for them?

Comment: @iayork I'm not claiming or suggesting anything. It would take some effort, but I would believe it if the answer to my question was "yes." (I don't read physics papers, but maybe they're complex enough and have enough work to go around to allow for hundreds of authors. An example might help; the [one I saw linked to above](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.191803#fulltext) lists "[object Object]" under "AUTHORS & AFFILIATIONS," so it's not very helpful in that regard.)

Comment: @shokhet [Physics paper sets record with more than 5,000 authors](http://www.nature.com/news/physics-paper-sets-record-with-more-than-5-000-authors-1.17567) and [Fruit-fly paper has 1,000 authors](http://www.nature.com/news/fruit-fly-paper-has-1-000-authors-1.17555) are the first and second hits for me on a google search for [papers with over a thousand authors](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=papers+with+over+a+thousand+authors&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: ... [Multiauthor Papers: Onward and Upward](http://archive.sciencewatch.com/newsletter/2012/201207/multiauthor_papers/) and [Scientific papers get more authors](https://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2016/11/daily-chart-18) give many more examples ("*Editors of physics journals do not bat an eye about papers with hundreds and, lately, even thousands of authors.*") and discuss trends and conventions.

Answer (score 4):

Some responses I don't think I've seen, yet, as well as some backup to former responses...

- Oftenimes, other authors have different roles at the same conference, at the same time, such as presenting a different paper, serving a role at a division committee business or admin meeting, or they may be attending another panel session about work in their same area(s).
- Sometimes it's because they are, for instance, on a different teaching schedule or invited profs at international universities, as opposed to just lacking monetary resources. Larger schedules conflict.
- Monetarily and to my last point, many/most schools don't offer adequate travel expenses to co-authors. Before recently retiring, at the end of June, 2017, I had a budget of $2,500/yr., which, at least in my field, was EXCELLENT, and based on a long-term endowment from the E.W. Scripps Foundation, which most J-schools don't have, even though it could only be used @ $1,250/conference, for up to two conferences per year. While my colleagues would often be rather amazed at that base amount of funding--which could be supplemented by funds from other accounts, such as grants or other projects that rewarded one with monies toward university-based projects--at the same time, there were other restrictions on how that base money could be spent. If I were "SIMPLY" a second or later author on a single paper, I could only get up to 50% of the base funding -- $625. While, at many schools, that can be a good deal of subsidy, it doesn't go far, in covering expenses to major cities, for a few nights. It would barely cover the costs of the flight and maybe conference registration, leaving one with all the hotel and per diem costs.
- As a tip to young scholars "new to the other side," to avoid such problems, it's always good to do some networking and/or to actually "co-present" a paper with a graduate student. Networking, one can usually pick up a side-gig as an officer in a division, let a research chair know--as soon as a paper is accepted--that you're willing to serve as a moderator, discussant, or panelist, in a discussion session (although the last often requires input well before even entering an article into competition). Co-presenting a paper with a graduate student who has worked on an article or is the main author has benefits of helping to "craft" your students and introduce them to others, afterwards, and it can also help them to get funding they might otherwise be unable to receive.

(Never underestimate the good that can come from crafting and polishing a couple/few rough diamonds or straight-up high potential grad students at a time. If well-trained, they can become great students and profs, at times going on to be lifelong colleagues you place in doc schools and/or as profs. With your main expertise as their starting point, they will often do very creative work that branches off slightly from or continues on, in your tradition, and they will often have some great insights, along the way.)

- It may be that such grad students are simply unable to attend, for other reasons, such as moving schools, as they progress, or it may be that they didn't have a great deal of expertise/anything of substance to add to the specific discussion that I/another author didn't already know, *in toto*. In my field of media psychology, there are often 2-4 authors (or maybe 5-7, if a school has a system of "milking" authorships, by having several (usually grad) authors each spread out tiny duties (heheheh) from their projects, so that all, like, 7, could be on all 7 papers, as authors (Michigan State's Mass Comm used to be famous, for that in the '90s and early-mid aughts, until people caught on...)), but, say, two out of four of my students/co-authors simply coordinated my lab and ran our experimental participants, for the time, and then co-wrote the (always essentially banal/straightforward/specific) methodology section, because they had the most direct experience with the process. Such beginner or "helper" authors are rather "insignificant," *in presentation*, and any questions, should the section not have been specific enough for direct replication--or If I didn't specifically remember--can be referred to those authors, by email or whatever (even face-to-face, later at the conference) -- as can any others who may be more "important," if any of the other situations mentioned occurs, wherein a more "essential" author is unavailable at presentation. If seemingly worth it, you might set up to have coffee or a drink with your co-author and the questioner, if it seems worth the effort. It could yield a cite and future interest in your work.
- All-in-all, most presentations--especially given time constraints--don't offer the opportunity for more than, say, two authors, at most -- and that's generally if they're both basically co-equals, bringing together different areas of expertise in a presentation. Otherwise, there's the mentoring grads model I expressed above.

!! Oh, yeah, and there's one last reason about which I just thought: the co-author is retired. My graduating doc student is presenting what is essentially his dissertation, which he defended this spring and which we'd since worked into a much more concise and expert piece--wherein I added a lot of my personal insights into theory and applications--but I'll be damned if I'm going to shell out $1,500+ on my own dime, to go help present that paper, in Chicago, next month (although I'm helping put together the presentation materials) -- especially on retirement money. He's presented several, at this point--including a starter, with me--and he knows my arguments in the article VERY well, having had to answer for them, in his defense (after submitting it to the grad school, finished, I tightened up and made the arguments more precise and forceful). Plus, it's his time to start carrying the torch, on his own, as my latest and perhaps best...

(My apologies for going a bit off topic, at times, but I seemed to read more into the question than was specifically articulated, although I do think fleshing it out, as such, should be very helpful. It sounds like a grad student question (as a matter of experience). This is also my first post on this site. I guess that's what you do, 12 days into retirement, at 4 in the morning. ;) Hope that all helped, in broader and specific senses. I'll get the hang of it...)

Thanks for the Opportunity,
Carson B

Comment: At the university I was at during 1993-1996, I had $50 (not a typo) per year available for travel expenses. I never bothered trying to get reimbursed, but I was able to get lodging taken care of by the 5 research-oriented conferences I attended in this time. (I just paid my own way to a few Mathematical Association of America section meetings, which were mostly teaching focused.) Similarly during 1996-1999, but in that case I was teaching at a high school, not a university.

Answer (score 3):

In my field, the professor or leader of the research group is the mastermind behind the research going on in their labs. They will have a number of PhD students working on different parts of projects and then they will present the overarching story either in a conference talk or in a paper.

Sometimes, part of the work — significant for the results achieved but pointless by itself — has been performed by collaboration partners. In that case, the part of the talk usually sounds something like:

> We sent this compound to the group of Mastermind to find out whether it glows in the dark.

Again, we have the presenting professor with the big picture who brings all loose ends together. It only makes sense that they do the talk.

The final slides are then usually the acknowledgements. Here, I am used to the professors saying exactly which PhD/Postdoc performed which work and which collaborator did what.

---

It’s not that those collaborators who are not on stage prefer sitting in the back or writing papers. Rather, they have different research interests, sometimes even sub-fields. They will go to those conferences that better fit their research, hold talks there and maybe mention the collaboration with the professor we just talked about if it fits into their story.

And it’s not that the PhD students and Postdocs prefer to sit back and write papers. They will either be in the lab working hard or they will be there listening, maybe presenting a poster.